# A tag for questions about the Esperanto special letters

Tags: discussion, tags

It is clear that we need a tag dealing with the special letters of the Esperanto alphabet. However, what should it be? Some questions have gone through a cycle of different tags, including

- chapelitaj-literoj
- accented-letters
- accents

Other possible tags include

- diacritics
- diacritical-marks

What should the preferred tag for these question be?

Answer (score 5):

[accents](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accents) would be wrong, contrary to what I initially thought, since the breve is not an accent, but a diacritic; it could also confuse the users who could think it is also for the pronunciation or the way to put emphasis on a word.
[diacritics](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diacritics) and [diacritical-marks](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diacritical-marks) would be synonyms; I would rather use the shorter one.

I would avoid to use tags in Esperanto, if there is an English phrase that can be use to describe the concept behind the tag. In some cases, we could use a tag in Esperanto, but not to generally mean *the tag is about Esperanto, not other languages* because *Esperanto Language* is about Esperanto (the language and the Esperanto culture).

Answer (score 5):

Wouldn't the most straight-forward categorization be an [alphabet](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alphabet) tag?

That covers the 22 Latin characters as well as the addition of diacritic marks. It also covers sounds values, the problems associated with alphanumeric keyboards versus handwritten text, the use of diagraphs and other workarounds, and more recently the implementation of the Esperanto alphabet in the UNICODE standard.

In the context of an Esperanto Language site, this categorization seems perfectly fitting.

Comment: _Alphabet_ doesn't generally include the diacritics added to the letters, or the [Italian alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_orthography) would include more than 21 letters. _Sounds values_ are considered _pronunciation_.

Comment: in Esperanto, it does belong to the alphabet, so I wouldn't directly vote down this suggestion.

Comment: this seems like the obvious choice to me.

Answer (score 0):

My preference is still

- chapelitaj literoj

because this makes it clear that it deals with just those special letters occurring in the Esperanto alphabet.

Comment: Why *ch* and not *ĉ*?

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev: In tags, only a very small character set is supported (mainly 0-9a-z and a few other characters), ĉ is not among them.